# How to ensure my software is not easy to pirate

Tags: python, python-3.x, web, anti-piracy

I want to make my python program less pirateable. I know it's fruitless to make it entirely secure, but I want it to be at least somewhat easier than copying copying the installer and throwing it on piratebay.

I've looked into verifying the MAC address of the user, but that either requires them to run the software first, or to give me their MAC address to get the software.

I've also looked into spreading out the files after installation, but once again that only works if they don't just copy the installer

It's python, so it's not going to be hard to reverse engineer, and it's a desktop application, so it's going to be pirated. But a tiny amount of security will prevent the average user from just pirating it I hope.

Answer (score 3):

The only secure way to prevent piracy is to make a crucial portion of your software server-side, and require that the user be connected to the Internet when running your software.